# Moving files from local to live via FTP

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to move my local Magento site to my Live server. (MAMP to cPanel)

To do this I have exported the database, etc and all those steps are fine.

However when I copy my local Magento files from Application/MAMP/htdocs to my FTP client (cyberduck) and choose to overwrite the existing Magento files, to ensure that all my local updates will be moved to the live site, it takes hours to overwrite and then says it has failed!

Does anybody know if I am doing this step correctly, or is there a different way to get my Magento files from my Local site to my Live site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento has about 16k files. I don't think moving them 'one by one' using FTP is the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your cPanel has option file manager and extraction compressed (zip, gzip) files. Most of hosts has such functionality. If has, compress your local root directory and upload it via FTP, after that you can extract files via cPanel.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is this they correct way to do it or is there not one specific way?

Now that I have done this, I am having problems with the rest of the steps to move my site from Local (MAMP) to Live (using cPanel), mainly moving my database from Local to Live, I thought I new how to do it but I don't. I have read so many articles and forums and they are all telling me to do different things! Some say to edit this or edit that and others say delete this or delete that! I don't suppose you could point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: This is alternative and simple way to do production. If you want professional development process, you should teach version control systems (git, svn). See references: [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431125/Choosing-a-Version-Control-System-A-Beginners-Tour), [this](http://biz30.timedoctor.com/git-mecurial-and-cvs-comparison-of-svn-software/), [and this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326429/what-version-control-system-is-most-trivial-to-set-up-and-use-for-toy-projects)

Comment: Thanks again for the help. After reading through the links you provided me with, it is clear that VCS is far more complex a system than I need.
All I need to do is move a website I have created Locally (MAMP) to my Live domain (through cPanel). I have created my site using Magento.
I have been following step-by-step instructions from articles such as [this](http://www.dmarkweb.com/how-to-move-magento-from-local-to-live-server.html) to try and help me do it, but it seems like I constantly go wrong, making me doubt the articles. You don't happen to know an article that works!? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have SSH access? I would recommend using rsync if you want to transfer files like this.

```
rsync -avz /path/to/project/on/local/ user@127.0.0.1:/root/to/magento/on/live
```

Further to that use something like Git as a deployment tool. That is what we do and it will apply any modifications on version controlled files to the live site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry but I don't know what SSH is? I have researched Git and it is definitely to complex for what I need. Like I have mentioned in the comment above, I am simply wanting to move my website from Local to Live but every article I read I seem to stumble. I really need something that explains the step-by-step process simpler or in more depth. Sorry to sound stupid but I am new to programming and Magento. I have managed to create my site by myself, and although this seems a simple task I seem to be struggling! Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to upload your stuff zipped/tared/gziped/whateverArchiveYouPrefer and then connect with ssh or write a php script to unpack the stuff.

Doing magento without ssh is hell on earth. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry but I am unfamiliar with ssh. Please take a look at the comment I have wrote above and I would be grateful if you could be of help. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I learned SSH from my collegues and I think it is good to learn it from someone you know to ask questions all the time. I don't have any resource to learn SSH. What is SSH? Secure Shell is like executing cmd.exe on a windows machine but remote. And a second note: You want to use a VCS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408450/why-should-i-use-version-control